# Circles related

Tags: geometry, circles

**My question needs a diagram. But, being a new user I cannot upload images in questions. So, below is the link to the diagram.** *[Diagram not to scale]*

https://photos.app.goo.gl/2jsB35Rp5Dc6vni13

In the figure, $O$ is the centre of the circle. If $ AB = 6 cm$ and $ AC = 5 cm$, then the product of $AO$ and $AX$ is?

Comment: in picture $CX > BX$ that's why $AB$ should be less than $AC$, but $6 > 5$.

Comment: I edited the question. The diagram is not to scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let's denote $a=|BC|$, $b=|AC|$, $c=|AB|$, $h=|AX|$,
$R=|OA|=|OB|=|OC|$
and let $[ABC]$ be the area of $\triangle ABC$.

To find the value of $h\cdot R$, we can use 
the two well-known
expressions for $[ABC]$,

\begin{align}
\text{1) in terms of the base $a$ and height $h$ }\quad
[ABC]&=\tfrac12 a\,h
,\\
\text{and 2) in terms of the sides $a,b,c$ and the circumradius $R$ }\quad
[ABC]&=\frac{abc}{4R}
,\\
\text{hence, }\quad
\require{cancel}\tfrac12 \cancel{a}\,h &=\frac{\cancel{a}\,b\,c}{4R}
,\\
h\,R&=\tfrac12\,b\,c
=\tfrac12\,5\cdot6=15
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b,c$ be the lengths of sides $BC,AC,AB$, respectively.

Let $R$ be the length of $AO$, and let $h$ be the length of $AX$.

Given $b=5$ and $c = 6$, the goal is to find $hR$.

By the extended law of sines, ${\large{\frac{a}{\sin A}}} = 2R$, hence $R = {\large{\frac{a}{2\sin A}}}$.

Let $k$ denote the area of triangle $ABC$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&\frac{1}{2}ah = k = \frac{1}{2}bc\sin A\\[4pt]
\implies\;&h = \left(\frac{bc}{a}\right)\sin A\\[4pt]
\implies\;&hR = \left(\left(\frac{bc}{a}\right)\sin A\right)\left(\frac{a}{2\sin A}\right)\\[4pt]
&{\phantom{hR}}=\frac{1}{2}bc\\[4pt]
&{\phantom{hR}}=15\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Can anyone please explain the Law of Sines to me?

Comment: @Aditya Pratap Singh:
$$$$
$\qquad$http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofSines.html
$$$$
$\qquad$https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines
$$$$
$\qquad$https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-trig/hs-geo-law-of-sines/v/proof-law-of-sines
$$$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $H$ be the midpoint of $AB$. We have $\angle ACX=\angle AOH$ (inscribed and half central angle subtending the same arc), hence triangles $CAX$ and $AOH$ are similar and:
$$
AO:BH=AC:AX,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
AO\cdot AX=BH\cdot AC=3\cdot5=15.
$$

[image]